# Oracle characterSet setting

Tags: php, oracle, adodb-php

I have a problem with special chars like "Ñ", "á" using adodb in ORACLE:
when save in varchar2/varchar field de table save other char "¿".

if connect with oci8 conect (direct to oracle) special char are correctly save.

How to set a characterset when connect ?

`($db->Connect(TNS_database, USER, PASSword));`

Thanks !!!

Comment: What is the database character set in `v$nls_parameters`?

Comment: From NLS_DATABASE_PAREMETER
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: Have a simple look at [oci_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) documentation

Answer (score 1):

With ADOdb, you should set the Oracle 'client' (i.e. PHP OCI8) character set. There are two ways to do this:

- In the shell that starts PHP you could set the environment variable `NLS_LANG` to something like ".AL32UTF8" (with the leading full stop).  If PHP is invoked from a web server, then you need to make sure you set this variable in the right place with the right syntax.
- Alternatively you can use some ADOdb function like [setConnectionParameter](https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setconnectionparameter) or maybe [setCharSet](https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:setcharset).  It's not clear to me the exact syntax to use for Oracle.  You will need to do some debugging through the stack.  What you want is `$this->charSet` in https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/blob/v5.21.0/drivers/adodb-oci8.inc.php#L253  to be the string `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: Can you share which solution you used?